# Redirect to Frontend app after successful login in keycloak

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect, spring-cloud-gateway

I have react application which connect to resource server though spring cloud gateway.Now if user is not authenticated Spring Cloud Gateway redirect request to Keycloak login page,after successful login and getting the reponse from the api, I need to redirect to frontend application but it's showing api response in the browser.Below is oauth config in api gateway.

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      provider:
        my-keycloak-provider:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:8055/auth/realms/webstore
      registration:
        keycloak-spring-gateway-client:
          provider: my-keycloak-provider
          scope: openid
          client-id: ecom-client
          client-secret: TUPr0SdFZCIftOaFcxfs8kz5CySlt6rX
          authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
          redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/keycloak"
```

so spring cloud gateway exchanging authrization code with keycloak and get accesstoken and after successful login it storing access token in session. I need to redirect to frontend application after successful login.And this is keycloak client config,here you can see redirect login url is cloud gateway oauth2 config which is provided by spring.

[image]

and my react login method is

```
  login(url: string): void {
     this.fullUrl = base_url + url;
     console.log(this.fullUrl);
     window.location.href = this.fullUrl;
  }
```

I need to redirect to my frontend app after successful login.

Answer (score 0):

consider using `keycloak-js` library instead of doing all this by yourself. You will have option to provide `redirectUri` in the `login` method.

Doc: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_javascript_adapter

If you are using `Next.js` as well, then you can consider using `NextAuth.js` which provides option for `callbackUrl` in its `signIn` method.

Doc: https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#specifying-a-callbackurl

Comment: Maybe he (she?) wants to achieve BFF which is quite trandy lately...

Comment: @ch4mp what is BFF?

Comment: **B**ackend **F**or **F**rontend. It's a pattern where browser clients (React app in this case) are not  OAuth2: it is secured with sessions (as opposed to Bearer access-tokens) against an intermediate backend (`spring-cloud-gateway` in this case) which is the OAuth2 client and replaces the session with an access-token before forwarding the request to the resource-server. The aim is to hide tokens from Javascript code running on "public" clients.

Answer (score 0):

- declare the gateway as a client (like you did)
- ensure you activated the `TokenRelay` filter
- serve both the API and the browser app through the gateway
  Here is a sample gateway conf

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:8442/realms/master
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
        registration:
          spring-addons-confidential:
            provider: keycloak
            client-id: spring-addons-confidential
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            scope: openid,profile,email
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
      - TokenRelay=
      - RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
      - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
      routes:
      - id: users
        uri: http://localhost:6443/users
        predicates:
        - Path=/users/**
      - id: ui
        uri: http://localhost:4200/
        predicates:
        - Path=/ui/**
```

Done:

- the browser app is now accessible from `http://localhost:8080/ui` (or whatever socket you configured the gateway with)
- first access to the UI will require the user to authenticate against the authorization-server
- requests sent by the UI to `http://localhost:8080/users/**` will be secured with sessions and the gateway will replace the session cookie with a `Bearer Authorization` header containing an access-token before forwarding the request to the resource-server.

I have just written [a short tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff) for that. As you can guess from the port of the UI, it is using an Angular app, but this really is an implementation detail: the only thing specific to the BFF pattern in there is setting a `base href` matching the route declared for it in the gateway. Nothing related to authentication nor OAuth2 => switching to React (or anything else) is trivial.